# What does this SQL related question mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just to be clear, I'm not expecting anyone to answer this question for me. I just want to know what the question is asking me to do.

So I've been given five conceptual database tables to look at and I have to answer this question:

[image]

What am I being asked to do?

Are they asking me to create an insert table script? I'm confused.

Comment: "bring back the following data items" sounds like they want you to write a `SELECT` query to me.

Comment: Thanks Tim. That's what I thought. The part that confused me is that they said email address is the only one I will be starting with. Maybe it's WHERE clause as cosmin_popescu suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a `SELECT` statement with `WHERE email = "email_address"`, email being a column in your table

I suggest you to read a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/) about sql.

Comment: Thanks for the response cosmin_popescu. So they are just asking me to use the WHERE function to place the email address at the beginning of the query result? I've actually already done this, but I was thinking it can't be that simple. Maybe I'm overthinking it.

Comment: You're wecome. I am glad that my answer helped you. Have a nice day !